# Integration of Gaussian process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $\textbf{G}(t)$ be a zero-mean tight Gaussian process and $f(t)$ be a deterministic function. What theorem can be used to prove that $\int_0^\tau \textbf{G}(t)df(t)$ is a zero-mean Gaussian variable?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by converges in distribution to?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. There is no convergence here. What I meant is that whether the integral is a zero-mean Gaussian variable. I've changed the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think establishing convergence in distribution of the sums whos limit defines your integral is relatively straightforward; just work with the characteristic function of the appropriate sums (and the fact that $G$ is Gaussian) then take the limit. If you're just going for convergence in distribution you won't have to worry about subtleties in commuting a limit with an integral. I'm also not aware of the meaning of what a "tight" process is but presumably it will tell you something about the first and second moment properties of $G(t)$ which you will need once you take the limit. You almost certainly need $f$ to have bounded variation I think because you will have to do Riemann-Stieltjes integrals of the type $\int \mu(t) \mathrm{d}f(t)$ and similar for the second moment.

EDIT: A little more details. We know that 
$ \operatorname{E}\left(\exp\left(i \ \sum_{\ell=1}^k (f(t_\ell)-f(t_{\ell-1})) \ \mathbf{G}(t_\ell)\right)\right)
\\ = \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2} \, \sum_{\ell, j} \sigma(t_\ell,t_j) (f(t_\ell)-f(t_{\ell-1})) (f(t_j)-f(t_{j-1})) + i \sum_\ell \mu(t_\ell) (f(t_\ell)-f(t_{\ell-1}))\right).$

Since $G$ is Gaussian. Take the limit as $k \to 0$ (such that the partition of $t_\ell$ is refining), then the sums in the exponential turn into Riemann-Stieltjes integrals, the one with $\sigma$ is a double integral.

Comment: Thank you Sikorski for your answer. It's very helpful. You are right that the function $f$ is of bounded variation. The "tightness" of Gaussian process is described [here](http://www.bios.unc.edu/~kosorok/current.pdf). I am still trying to grasp it, but I think it ensures some level of continuity in the sample path to give the desired properties of first and second moments as you mentioned. But I don't know where it exactly connects with the proof you outlined.

Comment: The document is very long and did not seem to have an index but some level of continuity should give you that the R-S integral exists (together with the fact that f had bdd variation). You can also probably use something like a Holder inequality to bound the integrals you get.

Comment: Sorry I realized that I didn't provide a page number for the description of tightness. It's on page 15 of the book [here](http://www.bios.unc.edu/~kosorok/current.pdf). Anyhow, I think I now have a general direction for tackling this problem, so again, thank you very much!

Comment: What if we talk not about a Riemann-Stieltjes integral, but about Lebesuge integral? Suppose we have the random variable $\int_\mathbb{R} G(t) d\mu(t)$. How do we prove this is a Gaussian random variable?

Comment: Apologies for bumping this up but the above answer only shows that for a fixed $\tau$, $h(\tau) = \int_0^{\tau} G(t)\, df(t)$ is Gaussian, which is what the original question was about. What if we want to show that $h(\tau)$ is a Gaussian process?