# Reference: Gaussianity of linear functional of Gaussian process

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, probability-theory, reference-request, duality-theorems

My question is similar to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669134/integration-of-gaussian-process), but I'm looking for a **reference** rather than derivation.  I've been told, inserting my own commentary in square brackets,

> If you take $X$ in $C([a,b])$ [i.e., $X$ is a Gaussian process with sample paths in the space of continuous functions on the interval $[a,b]$], then $b^*(X)$ is Gaussian on the real line for any $b^*$ in the dual of $C([a,b])$, which is the space of [integrals against] measures of bounded variation.

"Continuity" is with respect to, e.g., the "intrinsic semimetric" in [van der Vaart and Wellner (1996, e.g. p. 41)](https://books.google.com/books?id=zdDkBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA424&dq=van+der+vaart+wellner+empirical+processes&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjN3e31ocvNAhXD0RQKHQUkAdwQ6AEIHjAA#v=snippet&q=intrinsic%20semimetric&f=false).  Of course, it's fine to have a result for a general Banach space and its dual, where this is just a special case.

I've been told to look in [Bogachev's "Gaussian Measures"](https://books.google.com/books?id=UtufBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA394&dq=bogachev%20gaussian%20measures&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false) (which I have from the library), but I have not spotted such a result; either the book is too dense, or I am too dense, or both.  (Maybe Definition 2.2.1(ii), p. 42?)

Comment: What exactly *is* your question? You have the correct definition in Bogachev's book: to say that $X$ "is Gaussian with values in $C([a,b])$" is to say that $X$ is a random element of $C([a,b])$ with the property that $b^*(X)$ is normally distributed for each $b^*$ in the dual of $C([a,b])$. Also, in the sentence ""Continuity" is with respect to, e.g., the "intrinsic semimetric"...", to what does "Continuity" refer?

Comment: I think you answered my question of whether Definition 2.2.1(ii) has the interpretation I was hoping for; if you don't feel too silly making it an "Answer" I'm happy to accept it.  Re: continuity, with C([a,b]) the "continuous" functions on [a,b], I thought (think?) whether a given function is "continuous" depends on what metric you have on [a,b].  But, this seems perhaps irrelevant for my actual question, which you answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the correct definition in Bogachev's book: to say that $X$ "is Gaussian with values in $C([a,b])$" is to say that $X$ is a random element of $C([a,b])$ with the property that $b^∗(X)$ is normally distributed for each $b^∗$ in the dual of $C([a,b])$.